# mysql shows column based on values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question about querying data. When I want to get the specific colors(red and blue) of the selling items and its count from the following data

```
id  item    color
1   card    red
2   card    red
3   card    blue
4   card    blue
5   light   red
6   light   blue
7   light   yellow
8   cup red
9   cup red
10  cup blue
```

into this format

```
item    red blue
card    2   2
light   1   1
cup     2   0
```

I started  from this.

```
select item ,color, count(*) from shops where color in ('red','blue') group by item , color
```

But when I tried to separate "red","blue" into 2 columns. I have no idea how to do it. I would appreciate if someone could give some keywords or direction for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this:

```
SELECT item, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS red,
    SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'blue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS blue
FROM table_name
GROUP BY item;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with two counts, with a case inside them:

```
select  item,
        count(case when color = 'red' then item end) as red,
        count(case when color = 'blue' then item end) as blue
from    shops
group by item
```

Comment: Perhaps sum(case when color = 'red' then 1 else 0 end) as red

Comment: Isn't the same counting items where the color is red and null otherwise? Nulls will count as 0